# Best practice to check if a variable exists in plpgsql?

Tags: null, plpgsql, postgresql-9.1, exists

For instance I've got a stored procedure to import data from csv files and write the read data into a SQL table. 
I've got a table defined as below:

```
CREATE TABLE person (id int, name text, age int, married boolean);
```

First I check if the record exist already, if exists I do update, if doesn't - insert.
Each field of record may have a different type, so the result of a SQL command are assigned to a list of scalar variables:

```
SELECT name, age, married INTO v_name, v_age, v_married [..]
```

Let's assume every column is declared as optional (NULL allowed). What's the best way then to check which variable (v_name, v_age, v_married) is not NULL and can be processed?

I've found many solutions:

- IF NOT FOUND THEN
- WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
- IF v_age IS NOT NULL THEN [...]

or dynamic solution I'm using now using the last way I've mentioned above, when I have to check multiple columns (col):

```
list_of_columns := ARRAY['name','age','married'];
FOREACH x IN ARRAY list_of_columns LOOP
   EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || x
       || ' FROM person
            WHERE id = ' || quote_literal(v_id)
            INTO y;

   IF  x = 'name' AND (y != v_name OR y IS NULL) THEN
     UPDATE person
     SET    name = v_name
     WHERE  id = v_id;

   ELSIF x = 'age' AND (y != v_age OR y IS NULL) THEN
     UPDATE person
     SET    age = v_age
     WHERE  id = v_id;

   ELSIF x = 'married' AND (y != v_married OR y IS NULL) THEN
     UPDATE person
     SET    married= v_married
     WHERE  id = v_id;
   END IF;
END LOOP;
```

I'm looking for the best solutions having regard to the best practice and performance.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You don't have to be so harsh, If you can't understand what's written (and I don't blame you) I'll improve the question. For me my own code is completely understandable and sometimes is hard to judge or is it clear for others as well.

Comment: I've simplified it and changed names of the colums, hope now is better.

Comment: Better now. `person = v_person` is supposed to be `maried = v_married`?

Comment: hehe, sorry it's kinda late ;) exactly.

Comment: Typos are not a problem as long as you make yourself clear. :)

Comment: just a comment - dynamic SQL has not impact on "FOUND" variable and doesn't raise exception DATA_NOT_FOUND too. If you need it, you should to use GET DIAGNOSTICS statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, you can *radically* improve the whole procedure along these lines:

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_p ON COMMIT DROP AS
SELECT * FROM person LIMIT 0;

COPY tmp_p FROM '/absolute/path/to/file' FORMAT csv;

UPDATE person p
SET    name    = t.name
      ,age     = t.age
      ,married = t.person
FROM   tmp_p t
WHERE  p.id = t.id
AND   (p.name    IS DISTINCT FROM t.name OR
       p.age     IS DISTINCT FROM t.age  OR
       p.married IS DISTINCT FROM t.married);

INSERT INTO person p(id, name, age, married, ...)
SELECT id, name, age, married, ...
FROM   tmp_p t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM person x WHERE x.id = t.id);

COMMIT; -- drops temp table because of ON COMMIT DROP
```

#### Explain

- `COPY` your CSV file to a temporary table with matching layout. I copied the layout of the target table with `CREATE TABLE AS ... LIMIT 0`, you may need to adapt ...
- `UPDATE` existing rows. Avoid empty updates (nothing would change) with the last 3 lines in the `WHERE` clause.
  <strike>If you want to skip NULL values in the UPDATE (do you really?), use expressions like `COALESCE(t.name, p.name)`. That falls back to the existing value in the case of `NULL`.</strike> (May be useful, but that wasn't actually in your code.)
- `INSERT` non-existing rows. Use a `NOT EXISTS` semi-join for that.
- All in one transaction so you don't end up with a half-baked result in the case of a problem along the way. The temp table is dropped at the end of the transaction because I created it that way.

Comment: @Borys: Note the update with which I removed the `COALESCE` expressions - didn't fit the code in your question and makes more sense this way.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't it produce performance overhead by doing update/insert/create temp table every time even if it's not needed (record doesn't existst)?

Comment: @Borys: To be clear: this SQL script is run *once* per table, not per row as you seem to imply. Should perform *much* faster because it needs only a total of two SQL commands and manipulates only rows that need manipulating and only once. Your original code executes 1 + (number of columns) commands **per row** for the update alone - potentially updating the same row multiple times. Also, set-based operations are regularly *much* faster than iterating through rows one by one. Run a test, the difference should be evident.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Despite I cannot use this method to import data from file in this particular case (because of very small file size and validation issue) it'll be very helpful by other files. Especially this UPDATE - haven't seen before this construction.

Comment: @Borys: Speaking of which ... I fixed some typos to make the syntax valid.

Comment: @Borys: My answer is just *plain SQL*. If you wrap it into a plpgsql function, you have to loose the `COMMIT`, because every function is a transaction automatically and `BEGIN` has a different meaning. [Details about stored procedures / plpgsql functions in this related answer on dba.SE.](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/8189/3684)