# Can COPY be used with a function?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-copy

I've been tasked with profiling a postgresql database. The first requirement is to see how fast records can be added, with all possible external bottlenecks removed, in order to find our theoretical limit.

At first I created a csv file with sample data and read it in with the COPY function. Now, all records are added via a function `update_or_add()`. Is it possible to use COPY along with `update_or_add()` or is there a better solution that I haven't considered?

Comment: I posted sample code for a very similar question just yesterday [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13003402/939860).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than "for each row call update_or_add() on the row", your preferred approach should be to generalize "update_or_add" to work on all rows in a set.

`COPY` the data from the external source into a `TEMPORARY` or `UNLOGGED` table. Then write a query that merges the data from the copied table into your main table, like `update_or_add()` does but for all rows at once. If concurrent modification of the main table is possible this may require locking the main table with `LOCK TABLE main_table IN EXCLUSIVE MODE` so that other transactions can only `SELECT` from it while the merge is going on.

Without your schema or knowing what `update_or_add` does it's hard to say more. At a guess it's an upsert/merge function, in which case you can do its job *massively* more efficiently by locking the main table and doing a whole-set merge.